# Postpositive adjective placement

Tags: postpositive-adjectives

Are 'small' and 'tall' in correct position in 'boys from small to tall play soccer' that means small and tall boys play soccer--from smallness to tallness?

Comment: I have posted an answer. There is no need for you to write it in the title. If the moderator or any other person finds something incorrect, they will edit on their own. No need to mention it.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Have a great time while you are here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Boys from **small** to **tall** play soccer.

The correct words to be inserted here are:

> Boys from **short** to **tall** play soccer.

The positioning of the adjectives are correct, nothing wrong there. But it is more preferred to say *short* rather than *small* when height comparisons are made.

Also, it is shortness and tallness.

> **tallness** - the property of being taller than average stature.
>
> **shortness** - the property of being shorter than average stature.

Comment: I really appreciate you!!!